# Meteor collection find() does not retrieve any data

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm working through a meteor tutorial : https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/collections

I have a collection defined,

```
Tasks = new Mongo.Collection("tasks");
```

I've added two items to it, one directly from meteor mongo command line, and another one using:

```
Tasks.insert({ text: "Testing JS", createdAt: new Date() });
```

Here are the results from running db.tasks.find() on the backend:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("559e9569abbb64fe1d5fd89a"), "text" : "Hello world!", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-07-09T15:38:17.742Z") }
{ "_id" : "obRN8Rcssa9yJqXzA", "text" : "Testing JS", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-07-09T17:00:13.285Z") }
```

But when I run Tasks.find({}); on the front end, I get empty result. It just gives me a long JSON but no data from the database.

Comment: did you publish and subscribe to the collection or are you using autopublish?

Comment: I'm using autopublish for now. I'm trying to see if publish/subscribe flow works(I'm just working through a tutorial, in the future I will most likely use publish/subscribe)

Comment: I just tried removing autopublish and using subscribe/publish flow wiht same result.

Answer (score 3):

In meteor, you can view the documents returned by a cursor by calling [fetch](https://docs.meteor.com/#/full/fetch) on it. For example:

```
console.log(Tasks.find().fetch());
```

Comment: I just tried that : Tasks.find().fetch() It returns an empty array:
[]

Comment: On the client? If so, you'll need to publish and subscribe so the client has the data.

Comment: I have autopublish package installed, shouldn't it publish automatically?

Comment: Yes. Then there's something else going on. I notice that in your example, you have object ids instead of strings (meteor's default). Are you hosting your own database instead of using the default one that meteor creates for you? If so, I suspect the problem is that meteor isn't connected to it.

Comment: I pretty much ran the thing out of the box with "meteor create". Someone else on here said in past thread that when adding a record from command line in "meteor mongo", it uses object id's as strings. Let me try removing the records and then adding a record from meteor programmatically

Comment: Same result, i can see the collection on the backend, but it's not getting to the frontend.

Comment: I'm sure it's something simple, but I've asked all of the standard questions already. Can you reproduce it on meteorpad or give me a link to a repo on github?

Comment: Here is the repo with the entire folder I'm using: https://github.com/zlance/messing_with_meteor

Comment: You are not publishing a cursor. Modify your publish to `return Tasks.find();`. After making that change, the app seems to to work fine.

Comment: It's not writing to the database for some reason. It show on the screen until the page reloads. Also it doesn't display the record that is in the database.

Comment: I wish I had more to suggest, but it works fine for me which implies there is something very specific with your setup and I'm not sure how to debug more.

Comment: Well, the box I'm running this on had a MEAN stack from source installed earlier, let me roll it up in a clean VM.

Comment: I think the error was from me loading the app from just "meteor command" it works on meteor.com

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your code, you are not publishing anything:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
    console.log(Tasks.find());
  });   
}
```

needs to be

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.publish("tasks", function () {
    console.log(Tasks.find());
    return Tasks.find();
  });   
}
```

or just remove it if you use autopublish.

Comment: I updated the code and the repo as well to publish the data, it still doesn't work. I switched from autopublish to see if it's just an issue with autopublish, but it was doing the same.

Comment: I tried removing it and using autopublish with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the .js file of collection in front-end .js ?

```
import { Tasks } from '/your_path_goes_here/filename_goes_here.js';
```

If not import it and try below,

1. Add Publish like

   `if (Meteor.isServer) {
     Meteor.publish('tasks', function task() {
       return Task.find({});
     });
   }`
2. Subscribe it in Front-End .js

   `Meteor.subscribe('task');`